# IndexError: tuple index out of range in loading a model in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm a beginner and I'm learning, I found this project on GitHub and worked with it but in a part of the codes there is a problem that I cant's solve it, I think it's not hard to solve it but I don't know the bases behind Tensor and Keras, so I'm so thankful of people who help me to pass this problem and finish this project well.

This is the source of project [Recommender System](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10N5r8eLyUVy_7roubDcWeEEpHZuxK8O4#scrollTo=GTrSqh9BktbX)

This is the part where I ran into trouble:

```
scann_index_layer = \
tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.ScaNN(movielens_retrieval_model.query_model)

scann_index_layer.index_from_dataset(
    candidates_corpus_dataset.batch(100).map(lambda x: ( x, movielens_retrieval_model.candidate_model(x) )
    ))

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
  retrival_model_path = os.path.join(tmp_dir, 'retrieval_model')

scann_index_layer.save(
    retrival_model_path,
    options = tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(namespace_whitelist=['Scann'])
)

loaded_layer = tf.keras.models.load_model(retrival_model_path)

scores, movie_ids = loaded_layer(tf.constant([user_id]))

print(f"Recommendations for user {user_id} using ScaNN: {movie_ids[0, :5]}")
```

Comment: The `Recommneder System` link mentioned by you in the above issue detail is not accessible. Please provide some more details like which tensorflow and python version you are using along with reproducible code to replicate the error.